# Testing custom Logstash filters

Tags: testing, rspec, logstash, ansible

We are using Ansible and have Logstash.

How do I write a few tests to cover our custom logstash filters? What I want to do is this:

1. given a Logstash config with filters,
2. pass it a log line (or multiline log record),
3. see it successfully parsed into pieces.

I know there's this – https://github.com/elastic/logstash/wiki/Tips:Testing-your-filters, but I don't understand how this is useful – it appears outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer given by gmile works well up to version 1.5 of logstash. Since then, grok patterns were removed from the core and placed in logstash-core-patterns. What works for me in logstash 2.2 is:

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'spec_helper'
require "logstash/patterns/core"

# solution based on https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/blob/master/spec/filters/grok_spec.rb
module LogStash::Environment
  # running the grok code outside a logstash package means
  # LOGSTASH_HOME will not be defined, so let's set it here
  # before requiring the grok filter

  # the path that is set is the plugin root path
  unless self.const_defined?(:LOGSTASH_HOME)
    LOGSTASH_HOME = File.expand_path("../../../", __FILE__)
  end

  # also :pattern_path method must exist so we define it too

  # method is called by logstash-filter-grok to create patterns_path array
  #
  #   logstash-filter-grok/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb(line ~230):
  #
  #   @@patterns_path += [
  #     LogStash::Patterns::Core.path,
  #     LogStash::Environment.pattern_path("*")
  #
  # patterns defined in spec/patterns/ will be joined to the array by grok 

  unless self.method_defined?(:pattern_path)
    def pattern_path(path)
      ::File.join(LOGSTASH_HOME, "spec", "patterns", path)
    end
  end
end

require "logstash/filters/grok"
require "logstash/filters/<tested-plugin>"
```

the rest of the spec example is still valid.

As a new dependency requirement arrived, Gemfile also have to change. My gemspec dependencies are like this:

```
# Gem dependencies
s.add_runtime_dependency "logstash-core-plugin-api", "~> 1.0"
s.add_runtime_dependency "<tested-plugin>"
s.add_development_dependency 'logstash-devutils', '~> 0'
s.add_development_dependency 'logstash-filter-grok', '~> 3.2'
s.add_development_dependency 'logstash-patterns-core', '~> 4.0'
```

A full working exapmle can be found [here](https://github.com/thabiger/logstash-filter-rfc2047/blob/master/spec/filters/rfc2047_spec.rb)

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/blob/master/spec/filters/grok_spec.rb) and ended up with following working test code:

```
# simple_filter_spec.rb
#
# run using:
#   bundle exec rspec simple_filter_spec.rb

require "logstash/devutils/rspec/spec_helper"

LogStash::Environment::LOGSTASH_HOME = `gem which logstash-core`
module LogStash::Environment
  unless self.method_defined?(:pattern_path)
    def pattern_path(path)
      ::File.join(LOGSTASH_HOME, "patterns", path)
    end
  end
end


require "logstash/filters/grok"

describe LogStash::Filters::Grok do
  config <<-CONFIG
  filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}" }
      singles => true
      overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }
  }
  CONFIG

  sample "Mar 16 00:01:25 evita postfix/smtpd[1713]: connect from camomile.cloud9.net[168.100.1.3]" do
    insist { subject["tags"] }.nil?
    insist { subject["logsource"] } == "evita"
    insist { subject["timestamp"] } == "Mar 16 00:01:25"
    insist { subject["message"] } == "connect from camomile.cloud9.net[168.100.1.3]"
    insist { subject["program"] } == "postfix/smtpd"
    insist { subject["pid"] } == "1713"
  end
end
```

And my Gemfile looked like this:

```
source 'https://www.rubygems.org'

platform :jruby do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'logstash-core'
  gem 'logstash-devutils'
  gem 'logstash-filter-grok'
end
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the filepaths here? Are you running the tests on the Ansible controller, or on the Logstash server? Even with your `Gemfile` example, I'm unable to run your example spec file.

Comment: I had this error `NoMethodError: undefined method `pattern_path' for LogStash::Environment:Module`.  It seems one must add this to the file: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/pull/73/commits/0be653da88887b2b2413de543d03372a32244905

Comment: @conorsch See my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Logstash-Tester](https://github.com/gaspaio/logstash-tester) - a small tool to unit test your logstash filters and patterns. You write the test cases in json and logstash-tester runs them on logstash using a docker container. (Disclaimer: I wrote the tool)

Answer (score 0):

From [this blog](https://jsosic.wordpress.com/2015/12/13/rspec-tests-on-logstash-v1-5-and-v1-5/):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/elastic/logstash
$ cd logstash
$ git checkout 2.1
$ rake bootstrap
$ rake test:install-core
```

Instead of checking out the 2.1 branch, you should probably check out the tagged version of logstash you'll actually be running, e.g. v2.3.2 (note the leading "v").

After running the above commands, you can run `bin/rspec /some/path/your_filter_spec.rb` in the logstash repo.

**Important**: I found that the encoding line `# encoding: utf-8` is required, otherwise the match will fail.

Sample test file:

```
# encoding: utf-8

require "spec_helper"

describe "simple request log" do
  config (<<-CONFIG)
  filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
    }
  }
  CONFIG

  sample '55.3.244.1 GET /index.html 15824 0.043' do
    insist { subject['client']   } == '55.3.244.1'
    insist { subject['method']   } == 'GET'
    insist { subject['request']  } == '/index.html'
    insist { subject['bytes']    } == '15824'
    insist { subject['duration'] } == '0.043'
  end
end
```